# Where to find out recent IDE error in Android studio

Tags: android

Is there a place to find out the internals errors that has happened in IDE or the ones that I have reported in Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

You can find these in the build logs. On Windows:

1. Go to Help in the toolbar
2. Click Show Log in Explorer
3. It will direct you to a .txt log file of build actions and errors etc.

You can also see recent IDE errors in the notifications tab on the left hand side of the screen in the studio.
[image]